# Drag and Drop div weird behavior

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a multiple `div` drag and drop that can dynamically add more `divs` or remove some.

In the first time it works just fine, but if i try to run the function again it acts weirdly.

- It moves by dragging in any location, not only in the title as before.
- All movements goes to the last div.
- Can't write in the textarea anymore.

```js
var applyDrag = () => {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".contentCon")).forEach(e=>{
        
        e.querySelector("h1").onmousedown = null;
        dragElement(e);
        console.log(e.querySelector("h1").innerText);
    });
}

applyDrag();

var moveRoom = document.querySelector(".mainCon");

function dragElement(elmnt) {
    elmnt.style.background = "blue";   
    var dragEl = elmnt.querySelector("h1");
    dragEl.style.cursor = "move";
    console.log(dragEl.innerText);
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    if (moveRoom) {
        moveRoom.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    } else {
        dragEl.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        console.log(dragEl);
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="mainCon">
        <div class="contentCon" id="mainCode" style="position: absolute;"> 
            <h1>Main block</h1>
            <button onclick="applyDrag()">Submit</button>
            <br>
            <textarea cols="10" rows="10" spellcheck="false">Click the "Submit" button to run the Drag and Drop function again.
Internal code not applied.</textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="contentCon" style="position: absolute;"> 
            <h1>Exit log</h1>
            <br>
            <textarea id="ExitLog" cols="10" rows="10" spellcheck="false" readonly style="cursor: auto; width: 300;">Internal code not applied.</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code and your explanation is quite confusing. Which function do you mean in "run the function again"? `applyDrag` doesn't seem it was designed to be run multiple times. The code is a strange mixture of new style (`querySelector`) and ancient style (`e || window.event` and assigning events with `on...`properties instead of `addEventListener`). More over there is a modern drag-and-drop API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please replace these lines in dragElement function.

```
if (moveRoom) {
    moveRoom.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
}
else {
    dragEl.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
}
```

and just make it

`dragEl.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;`

it is working on first run because on first call moveRoom is null that when else part run and onmousedown function is assigned properly to dragEl but on second run it is not null and onmousedown function is assigned to moveRoom element.